# Trying to mix while and raw_input commands

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, raw-input

I'm very new to python IDLE, I have been tasked with making a game that asks you to guess a random number, here is what I have but whatever I type in it returns "you were too high" a little help would be very appreciated thanks.

```
import random
i = random.randint(0,100)
print (i)

e = raw_input ("Guess what number I'm thinking of between 0 and 100!")
while e != i:
     if i > e:
        print "You were too low."
     elif i < e:
        print "You were too high."
     e = raw_input ("Guess what number I'm thinking of between 0 and 100!")
if e == i:
    print "yay"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **typecast** your return call using `raw_input`, you're comparing ASCII values to integers, example `1` as an ascii character would be 0x31 (49), which compared to 1 is obviously higher. Every value you input is going to output as higher, simple do this to fix your issue.

> e = (int(raw_input("Guess what number I'm thinking of between 0 and 100!")))